# Snowflake SQL - How to represent decimal values to exponential value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-data-masking

I have the decimal values in my snowflake table and need to show exponential values

0.9525816643 --> 9.523E-1

0.9714426928 --> 9.714E-1

759023.356783 --> 7.59023E5

Which function I can use in snowflake to convert decimal to exponential value?

Answer (score 2):

To display numbers in this way you would need to cast them to text/char using an appropriate formatting string e.g. TO_CHAR(1234, '9D999EE')

It's described in a bit more detail [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html#fixed-position-format-elements)